# Changed HTML, now child inputs are not accessible in each()

Tags: jquery, dynamic, tabs, each

I think the problem is more fundamental with manipulating the DOM, but don't know how to  verify.

So I've dynamically created tabs then added its corresponding div HTML using the HTML from another static tab div like so, which works great:

```
    $('#specific-tab').html($(this).closest('div').html() ); 
//where this is always one line away from closest('div') to copy from, promise.
```

Then later, I have one each statement which goes through all input text boxes within all tabs:

```
$('#div-above-tabs input[data-item=specialvalue]').each(function() {
   $(this).change(function() {
    //do stuff
   });
});
```

This statement works perfectly on all tabs EXCEPT the dynamically created ones.

I've spent 8 hours verifying all referenced attributes, ids, classes and they are PERFECT and uniquely identified.

Is there a behavior with the DOM using these methods that I don't know about?

**EDIT**

The first snippet occurs on a change() trigger. The second occurs without a trigger, but is written much later in the code. Relevant?

Comment: Shouldn't be...as long as the elements are on the page when the `.each()` is called it should work. Can you make a fiddle showing the problem?

Comment: When does your second code snippet run in relation to your dynamic input creation? If it runs prior to creating your dynamic inputs then you'll need to use a [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) ("**[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**" in jQuery 1.7+) otherwise you'll have to ensure this snippet executes after the inputs are created. A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be helpful as well.

Comment: Let's say the first snippet occurs on change() of a different input, and the second snippet occurs openly, no triggers... but is later in the code.

Comment: @JoeReed can you create a demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Source order doesn't really matter in this case - it's execution order that's important.  Unless the second snippet runs after the change event executes, then it won't affect any new elements.  It has to RUN after the new elements are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
$('#div-above-tabs input[data-item=specialvalue]').each(function() {
   $(this).change(function() {
    //do stuff
   });
});
```

it should be

```
$('#div-above-tabs').on('change', 'input[data-item=specialvalue]', function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

because you have elements which are created dynamically under `div-above-tabs` but you are registering the `change` event handler on dom ready.

In this case you need to use delegated event handling using event propagation as given above

Answer (score 0):

This is only a guess but I'm thinking the .each function is analyzing the DOM before you are generating the tabs. You may want to to set up a listener on the inputs themselves based on what is inside of the entire tabs container instead of searching through each after the fact for a change? Again with limited information this is only a wild guess...This statement should keep any eye on any changes of your main tab container and catch changes even in inputs that are created after the DOM load...

```
$("#above_tabs_container").on("change","input[data-item=specialvalue]",function() {
   // do some function stuff
});
```

May be worth a try, I use $.on for tons of my dynamically loaded stuff and it seems to catch it as long as you watch the container that is in the DOM on load... http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Tom Pietrosanti was correct in the comments. The order of execution was the issue here. Since the change() on the first snippet wasn't executed until after the the rest was loaded already: the second each().

I would have used the .on() - great solution but 1.7+ isn't a choice, don't ask why.

All I had to do was add the each on a click event which was conveniently placed nearby.

This is a difficult concept to keep in mind as someone coming from a server side language - **ORDER OF CODE IS NOT NECESSARILY THE SAME AS ORDER OF EXECUTION**

Sorry about no jsfiddle everyone, next time. :)

Thanks so much for everyone's time, A LOT of good answers!